# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error

Tags: php, sql, yii, error-handling, yii2

I'm facing the above error problem when I'm trying to get the backup of DB table. Please Check

```
$table_name = "back_up_manager";
$backup_file  = "/var/www/html/solaris_dev/uploads/back_up_manager".date('F h:i:s').".csv";
$sql = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '$backup_file' FROM $table_name";
$command = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
```

Comment: What does your PHP error_log say? Have you looked at the stack trace?

Comment: Caused by: PDOException
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error.................... It is showing this error message there

Comment: You have a PDO Exception, good, you should also have a stack trace showing you the lines of code called

Comment: If @vahe 's solution doesn't totally work, you may look at removing the space from the filename. Linux servers typically don't like spaces in file names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chang this part of code

```
$sql = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '" . $backup_file. "' FROM " .$table_name;
```

In your example `$sql` variable contain invalid path  of file.

Comment: Should there not be a space and single quote after `outfile` and before `from`?

Comment: And I've added in the quotes for you :-)